# replace numeric string to number inside an array

Tags: javascript, arrays, reactjs, replace

I want to convert an array from

```
arr = ["step","0","instruction","1"]
```

to

```
newArr = ["step",0,"instruction",1]
```

here is my sample code:

```
  newArr = arr.map((x) => {
      if (typeof x === "number") {
        return x;
      }
    });
```

Comment: If you're not using the return value of `.map()` then `.map()` is the wrong tool.

Comment: What have you tried so far to solve this on your own? You should be able to find suitable solutions with your preferred search provider.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could check if the string is convertable to a finite number and map the number in this case.

```js
const
    data = ["step", "0", "instruction", "1"],
    result = data.map(v => isFinite(v) ? +v : v);

console.log(result);
```

If you need all other numbers as well, you could convert to number and check the the string of is against the value.

```js
const
    data = ["step", "0", "instruction", "1", "NaN", "Infinity"],
    result = data.map(v => v === (+v).toString() ? +v : v);

console.log(result);
```

Comment: And this is the first time someone asks such a question? Convert some "numbers" in an array into actual numbers?

Comment: Nope, see this post here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1133770/how-to-convert-a-string-to-an-integer-in-javascript . In That post however they don't account for the fact that not each value in the array is a number.

Comment: the problem is not the conversion, but the check if it is possible.

Answer (score 0):

I think you are looking for something like this:

```js
// Defining initial values
const initialValues = ["step","0","instruction","1"]

// Mapping initial values to a new parsed array
const parsedValues = initialValues.map(value => {
  // We try to parse the value. If it isNaN (Not a number) we just return the value e.g. don't change it
  if(isNaN(parseInt(value))) return value;
  // Else the value can be parsed to a number, so we return the parsed version.
  return parseInt(value);
})
// Printing the parsed results
console.log(parsedValues);
```

Answer (score 0):

try this:

```js
const arr = ["step","0","instruction","1"]

const newArray = arr.map(value => { //Iterate the array searching for possible numbers.
/* Check with function isNaN if the value is a number, 
  if true just return the value converted to number, 
  otherwise just return the value without modification */
  if (!Number.isNaN(Number(value))) { 
      return Number(value)
  }

  return value
})
```

Comment: You don't offer any explanation as to why and how this works.

Comment: @Flashtube fixed, ty for the tip!